# Is it possible to install gitlab using local IP address of machine instead of domain name?

Tags: git, gitlab, ip-address, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api

Is it possible to install Gitlab using the local IP address of the machine instead of domain name?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I installed GitLab server for testing on VMware. You can download GitLab server from bitnami.com and open it by VMWare. Then you can see GitLab server by an invalid IP.

https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/gitlab/15.4.3-ce.0-0/bitnami-gitlab-15.4.3-ce.0-0-linux-vm-debian-11-x86_64-nami.ova

Also you can use docker images for installing GitLab server or install manually it from [GitLab website](https://about.gitlab.com/install/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible. Just configure your `external_url` to point to `http://<iphere>`.